# Start the day off strong

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I do understand the meaning of "**Start the day off strong**", but I don't understand what this expression consists of, if I can put it like that. Is it the phrasal verb "**start off**"? Why isn't it "**Start off the day** strong" then? Perhaps this "off" has something to do with "strong"? But I doubt it. Anyway, could you specify, please, the parts of this expression and maybe provide a few more examples like this. Thanks a million!

Comment: You apparently know English better than me! I don't know what "Start the day off strong" means - apart from the fact that I'm *inclined* to think it's created by and/or aimed at non-native speakers. I wouldn't even know what it meant if it was syntactically valid ("Start the day off **strongly**"). Is it suggesting you should have a substantial breakfast to make sure you're full of energy? Or is "strong" here some kind of metaphorical usage?

Comment: For something that *does* make sense to me, *Start the day off with a smile* and *Start off the day with a smile* are both [perfectly valid, equally common, and mean exactly the same.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Start+the+day+off+with%2CStart+off+the+day+with&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Personally, I don't think it makes the slightest difference to the meaning whether ***off*** is included or not, but perhaps others feel differently about that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your comment sounded quite flattering, tbh, but it's because I'm not a native speaker. Anyway, the thing is that this expression is quite common in vlogs (I guess American vlogs), if you google "Start the day off strong", you'll find lots of entries and their meanings vary: from "A nutritious breakfast offers you the energy you need to start the day off strong", to "Many successful people have a preferred morning routine that they follow to start the day off strong.", so I guess it's not only about food.

Comment: Well, I'd like to see some evidence that these "vlogs" are in fact from native Anglophones. But it's certainly not "natural" English to me (in the UK) regardless of whether it's ***strongly*** or the "flat adverb" ***strong*** (which might work in some contexts, but *I strong maintain doesn't work in **all** contexts*).

Comment: Can't find the previous video by an American girl, but I have the link to a vlog by a Canadian https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtpyhrLpMMM (I hope I can post links here), 
9:51 going through these motions truly makes
9:53 you feel like you're starting the day
9:55 off strong

Comment: It's what I'd consider an "inspirational quote" [with all the negative connotations that carries]. It's a 'chivvy up', a 'motivator', the current incarnation of "Hang on in there" or "Think Different". it relies more on newspaperese & pizzaz than grammar.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: Maybe like McDonald's *I'm loving it*. Quirky syntax is an attention-grabbing device

Comment: The underlying well-established idiom is [***get off to a strong start***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+to+a+strong+start%2Cmake+a+strong+start%2Cstart+strong&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) - where it's worth noting that the entire sequence of 5/6  words is significantly more common than just the two-word collocation ***start strong***. I suggest learners should familiarize themselves with the more common usage first.

Comment: My first thought was that it could be an advertising slogan for coffee.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In GB there is actually statistical correlation between hot breakfasts and kids' GCSE and A Level results. Those getting four A-stars are more likely to have "started the day the greasy-spoon way".  There is far less evidence that the two things exist within a cause and effect relationship, however. There is no demonstrability that bacon and egg makes you think any faster or more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely correct that "start off" is a phrasal verb, and that native English speakers often insert an object into many phrasal verbs:

- **Tidy** the house **up**
- **Finish** your homework **off**
- Why are you **bringing** that **up**?
- **Call** your dog **off**

Sometimes it's more idiomatic to place the object after the verb phrase; sometimes one way might be more informal. There's no universal rule on this. Some phrasal verbs are peculiar to certain dialects or have different meanings - for example, '*wash up*' means do the dishes in British English, but means wash your body in US English. This will have an effect on how a verb phrase may be used.

Comment: Your first two examples correspond to OP's ***start off*** (minimally "phrasal verbs" where it makes no real difference whether the optional preposition is included or not). The other two examples are "true" phrasal verbs, but the preposition in example #3 is *required*, and the presence or absence of ***off*** in #4 changes the meaning anyway, so they're not the same as OP's example. Also, you don't explicitly address the fact that it's entirely optional whether the object goes ***inside*** the phrasal verb or ***after*** it - you only give examples of the first possibility.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so, a good, balanced selection of examples.

Comment: It would be more balanced if it included the other half: ***Tidy up** the house, **Finish off** your homework, Why are you **bringing up** that?, **Call off** your dog*.